# R forecast from STL

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I want to understand how forecast from STL function in R works. So, I am not giving any reproducible code here.

Below is the procedure that I worked on time series

1. I used STL decomposition on my time series.
2. Checked residuals component from step 1 for white noise using Box.test
3. Found that residuals are not white-noise. So, used ARIMA model to fit a forecasting model.

Now, my task is to compute forecast values that consist of a. Seasonal and Trend component from step 1 above b. Residuals component from ARIMA model - from step 3 above.

If I use

```
forecast(stl(..)),
```

it gives me

```
 Point Forecast     Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
```

However, I am interested in only seasonal and trend parts of forecast. How can I get seasonal trend components?

What components does constitute forecast(stl(..))

Comment: As far as I know, the function `forecast::forecast.stl` does not return forecasts for each component. According to the documentation, the forecasts are based on the seasonally adjusted data and then are re-seasonalized using the last year of the seasonal component. As an alternative approach, you may be interested in [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115506/forecasting-a-seasonal-time-series-in-r/115553#115553), which describes how to obtain forecasts for the trend and seasonal components, as well as for the overall series, based on the basic structural time series model.

Comment: @javlacalle, Thank you for replying. On my timeseries, fit methods are running forever.  Can I share my data with you to check? pls let me know

Comment: Feel free to post the data or email me the file and I will have a look.

Comment: @javlacalle, Thank you for extending help. I sent email to your yahoo.es account